# Search data from any column of the table from Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to implement one *search* logic here. What I want is,

*A user enters any text in the search box and presses enter*. Then what should happen is, it should search in the table on any column and it the record exist then it should display.

Currently what I tried is, it search from one of the column from the table. Below is the code,

```
PROCEDURE GET_SEARCH_DATA
(
  P_INPUTTEXT IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_RETURN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)

AS

BEGIN
  OPEN P_RETURN FOR
  
SELECT APP_MST_ID, APPLICATIONNAME, PROJECTNO, VSS_FOLDER_LOC FROM 
APPLICATION_MASTER WHERE APPLICATIONNAME LIKE  '%'|| P_INPUTTEXT || '%';
  
 END;
```

So what I want is, it should search from every column of the table and display the result.

Comment: You mean just multiple `LIKE` checks, one for each column, `OR`'d together? Or something more complicated? (Performance might be an issue with `LIKE`; maybe look at [Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ccref/oracle-text-SQL-statements-and-operators.html#GUID-4775F5FE-4569-4DF4-A7CA-B20EC6880CAB)?)

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add a bunch of `or` conditions to your existing `where` clause.

Comment: @AlexPoole: may be multiple `LIKE`. But user will add any text in the search box and if it exist in any column of the table then it should display the record

Comment: @AlexPoole: any suggestion on this ?

Comment: You know the table and column names so I'm not sure what the issue is; why can't you add `OR`'d conditions to what you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather rudimentary "solution" which checks all tables and their columns (from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`) and checks which ones of them contain a *search string*; it displays a table, a column and number of occurrences.

```
SQL> declare
  2     l_str   varchar2 (500);
  3     l_cnt   number := 0;
  4  begin
  5     for cur_r in (select u.table_name, u.column_name
  6                     from user_tab_columns u)
  7     loop
  8        l_str :=
  9              'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
 10           || cur_r.table_name
 11           || ' WHERE '
 12           || upper (cur_r.column_name)
 13           || ' like (''%&search_string%'')';
 14
 15        execute immediate (l_str) into l_cnt;
 16
 17        if l_cnt > 0
 18        then
 19           dbms_output.put_line (
 20              cur_r.table_name || '.' || cur_r.column_name || ': ' || l_cnt);
 21        end if;
 22     end loop;
 23  end;
 24  /
Enter value for search_string: MANAGE
EMP.JOB: 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for search_string: ACCOU
DEPT.DNAME: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```